# Unable to save images using gst appsrc pipline

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

i am required to save frames that i read using opencv video capture, when i try to convert the frames numpy to buffer and push it through the gstreamer pipline. No images get saved.

```
import gi
import cv2

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)

# Set up GStreamer pipeline
# pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("mfvideosrc device-index=0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! "
#                             "jpegenc ! multifilesink location=frame//frame_%05d.jpg")

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("appsrc name=source ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! "
                            "jpegenc ! multifilesink location=frame//frame_%05d.jpg")

# Get the appsrc element from the pipeline
appsrc = pipeline.get_by_name("source")

# Set the appsrc format and properties
# appsrc.set_property("format", Gst.Format.TIME)
# appsrc.set_property("is-live", True)

# Set the video format (width, height, and framerate) according to your requirements
video_width = 1280
video_height = 720
video_framerate = 30

# Create a VideoCapture object
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Replace with your video file path or device index if using a camera

# Set the desired video properties
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, video_width)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, video_height)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, video_framerate)

# Start the GStreamer pipeline
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# # Run the main loop
# loop = GLib.MainLoop()
# try:
#     loop.run()
# except KeyboardInterrupt:
#     pass


if not video_capture.isOpened():
    print('Failed to open camera')
    exit(-1)

# Main loop to read frames from VideoCapture and save them

try:
    frame_count = 0
    while True:
        # Read frame from VideoCapture
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        # # Convert the frame to RGB if needed
        # frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        print(frame.shape)
        # Convert the frame to a GStreamer buffer
        buffer = Gst.Buffer.new_wrapped(frame.tobytes())

        print(buffer.get_size())

        # # Set the buffer timestamp
        # buffer.pts = buffer.dts = frame_count * (1e9 / video_framerate)

        # Push the buffer into the appsrc element
        appsrc.emit("push-buffer", buffer)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Stop the GStreamer pipeline
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

So in the above code i can validate that the frames are read and convert to buffer but after appsrc.emit i dont see the images being saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you specify the caps for `appsrc`. These caps are important because GStreamer pipeline uses caps negotiation to ensure that all elements into the pipeline can handle the data produced by `appsrc`.
So, simply adding the caps property to `appsrc` allows buffers to flow so the JPEG encoded images happen to be saved:

```bash
- pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("appsrc name=source ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! "
                            "jpegenc ! multifilesink location=frame//frame_%05d.jpg")

+ pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("appsrc name=source caps=video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=BGR,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! "
                            "jpegenc ! multifilesink location=frame//frame_%05d.jpg")
```